# How can I read a bunch of TIFF files faster in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, tiff, imread

I have to read in hundreds of TIFF files, perform some mathematical operation, and output a few things. This is being done for thousands of instances. And the biggest bottleneck is imread. Using PixelRegion, I read in only parts of the file, but it is still very slow.

Currently, the reading part is here.

Can you suggest how I can speed it up?

```
for m = 1:length(pfile)
    if ~exist(pfile{m}, 'file')
        continue;
    end
    pConus = imread(pfile{m}, 'PixelRegion',{[min(r1),max(r1)],[min(c1),max(c1)]});
    pEvent(:,m) = pConus(tselect);
end
```

Comment: It is hard to say from this example how to help.  However, my first question would be did you initialize `pEvent` to the correct size prior to this loop.  If not then that assignment could get very slow after lots of iterations.  I don't know of anyway to speed up the imread though.

Comment: @AeroEngy Yes, actually I did. Thanks!

Comment: What type of images are they (e.g. 16-bpp Flate compressed)? Must you do this in matlab? Is speed more important than the programming environment?

Answer (score 2):

### General Speedup

- The pixel region does not appear to change at each iteration. I'm not entirely sure if Matlab will optimize the min and max calls (though I'm pretty sure it won't). If you don't change them at each iteration, move them outside the for loop and calculate them once.

---

### Parfor

The following solution assumes you have access to the parallel computing toolbox. I tested it with 10,840 tiffs, each image was 1000x1000 originally, but I only read in a 300x300 section of them. I am not sure how many big `pConus(tselect)` is, so I just stored the whole 300x300 image.

P.S. Sorry about the formatting. It refuses to format it as a block of code.

Results based on my 2.3 GHz i7 w/ 16GB of ram

- for: 130s
- parfor: 26s + time to start pool

% Setup

```
clear;clc;
n = 12000;

% Would be faster to preallocate this, but negligeble compared to the
% time it takes imread to complete.
fileNames = {};

for i = 1:n
    name = sprintf('in_%i.tiff', i);
    % I do the exist check here, assuming that the file won't be touched in
    % until the program advances a files lines.
    if exist(name, 'file')
        fileNames{end+1} = name;
    end 
end
rows = [200, 499];
cols = [200, 499];
pics = cell(1, length(fileNames));

tic;
parfor i = 1:length(fileNames)
    % I don't know why using the temp variable is faster, but it is
    temp = imread(fileNames{i}, 'PixelRegion', {rows, cols});
    pics{i} = temp;
end
toc;
```

Comment: Thank you. A quick question. Since this whole thing has to be done again and again, does the pool have to be started each time? Or is it a one time thing?

Comment: The pool only has to be started each time to open MATLAB (unless it goes to sleep). But it's basically a one time thing, and then you can run the code as many times as you want without having to restarting the pool.

Comment: Also, I would recommend you open up Activity Monitor/Task Manager/etc. to see what your cpu usage is like. If the default Matlab pool configuration does not saturate your cpu then you can manually increase the number of workers.